# Not Allow drop down null value selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 Application. Below is my model

```
    public class ViewModel
        {
public string AssignedUserName { get; set; }
          public IList<SelectListItem> PossibleAssignees { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<table style="width: 100%; ">
        <tr>
            <td>Assigned To:</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssignedUserName, Model.PossibleAssignees)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AssignedUserName, "Assigned To Required")</td>
<tr></table>
```

**PossibleAssignes is a dropdown, the values should be -> EmptyString,"Mr.Barr".**

So if the user selected EmptyString means i need to throw validation like " it is Required" field.

i tried with adding **[Required]** field validator. it is a collection which having some empty string values as drop down value,
so i am not sure how to use the **[Required]** field for collection which having  empty strings. 
i don't want to allow empty strings for dropdown.

how can i validate this ?

Comment: Show how you generate the dropdown in the view and the `IList<SelectListItem>`

Comment: @stephen updated the view code

Comment: If you change it to `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssignedUserName, Model.PossibleAssignees, "--Please select--")` it will render the first option with a null value which will trigger a validation error if selected

Comment: You also need to ad the `[Required]` attribute to property `AssignedUserName`

Comment: @stephen it will add"Please select" to drodown. i dont want this option

Comment: @stephen i am not sure where to add [Required] field validator. both  the properties ?

Comment: You dropdown is binding to `AssignedUserName` so if you want to validate it has a value (ie not null or an empty string) then you need to add `[Required]` as you have done for `Comment`

Comment: Are you saying that you have options that look like `<option value="">Mr. Barr</option>`, and if they are selected it should trigger a validation error?

Comment: @stephen got your point.

Comment: option looks like <option value=""></option><option value="Mr.B">MR.barr</option>

Comment: @stephen only two options. first one is empty and second one is having some value. thats it

Comment: Don't render the first option (exclude it from `PossibleAssignees`) and use what I showed in my 2nd comment (or as FabioG has used). This will correctly render the first option as `<option value>XXX</option>`. Note its `value` not `value=""` which is effectively null. And the text can be anything you want including an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't assign an emtpty string to the values in your list, use it as default value instead and the `[Required]` will work just fine.
In your view use it as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssignedUserName, Model.PossibleAssignees, String.Empty)
```

and in your viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
      [Required]
      public string AssignedUserName { get; set; }
      public IList<SelectListItem> PossibleAssignees { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** (i'll leave my first answer because it might work for someone else)

You can make a custom validation:

```
public class ViewModel
{
      [Required]
      [ValidateAssignedUserName()]
      public string AssignedUserName { get; set; }
      public IList<SelectListItem> PossibleAssignees { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string Comment { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateAssignedUserName : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Select a user.";

    public ValidateAssignedUserName()
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string user = value as string;

        if (user != null && user.Length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry.i am not able to understand this

Comment: what is the use of adding String.Empty to dropdown

Comment: @SivaRajini in PossibleAssignees don't include the empty string. The `String.Empty` will work as default value and validate as nothing selected

Comment: actually the value coming from remote service. so it will be bind model

Comment: @SivaRajini you can make a custom validation check the edited section of my answer

Comment: @FabioG. Your edit with the custom validation is unnecessary. Your `ValidateAssignedUserName` does exactly what the `[Required]` attribute does. You original answer is correct. OP is doing something else wrong if its not working.

Comment: @stephen for me [Required] Validator itself is working fine. Thanks for your help stephen. you taught me some thing

Comment: @Fabiog.Thanks for your help. i learned custom validation from your post.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use a custom model binder .e.g

```
public class ViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as ViewModel;

        if (model.AssignedUserName == "-1")
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("AssignedUserName", "No assignee selected");

        return model;
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // .....
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ViewModel), new ViewModelBinder());
    // ....
}
```

Change your view slightly :

`<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AssignedUserName)</td>`

Remove the text from the 2nd param for the above line.

Doing the above will result in `ModelState.IsValid` being set to `false`. When you render the view, the text "No assignee selected" will appear where the `ValidationMessageFor()` call is made.

So there are options to achieve what you need.